# How to change request headers with server middleware

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, nuxt-middleware

According to [server directory documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#server-middleware) of Nuxt 3, server middleware can be used to change request headers. I want to add an authorization header and attach a bearer token to my requests via server middleware.

```
// /server/middleware/auth.js
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  event.context.authorization = 'Bearer test';
  event.node.req.headers = {...event.node.req.headers, Authorization:'Bearer test'};
});
```

I tried above code and it works on every request, but it doesn't seem to add anything to request headers. How can I achieve this? Which property should I change?

Comment: @bn_ln No but I made a custom fetcher function inside the composables directory. It checks the cookies, and configures the request body by adding the bearer token then sends the request with useFetch.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

OP just clarified that the authorization is from a cookie session.

Example of cookie that is store in the browser.
[image]

You can use the `useRequestHeaders` [composable](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-request-headers#userequestheaders)

When requesting the API in the browser, it will be something like this.

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
const { data } = await useFetch('/api/test', {
  headers: useRequestHeaders(['cookie'])
})
</script>
<template>
  <div>
     Hello World
  </div>
</template>
```

In your server middleware e.g.
`~/server/middleware/log.ts`

```js
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
    const requestedURL = getRequestURL(event)
    if (requestedURL.pathname === '/api/test') {
        const cookieHeaders = getHeader(event, 'cookie')
        // console.log(cookieHeaders)
        if (cookieHeaders) {
            const cookieArr = cookieHeaders.split(';').map((c) => c.trim()) // ensure to remove white spaces
            cookieArr.forEach((cookie) => {
                // console.log(cookie)
                if (cookie.startsWith('authorization')) {
                    console.log(cookie)
                }
            })
        }
    }
})
```

[image]

Comment: I thought it's working at first but I guess it's not changing the request headers, it's changing the response headers...

Comment: Where does the authorization came from? is it from the cookie storage?

Comment: @MehmetAliKOÇAL, I've edited my post. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Although the server console shows the added header, there isn't any Authorization header on the browser console's network tab still... Btw yes, the token is coming from a cookie.

Comment: Got it, I've edited my answer again lol Hope this time that would help you

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I really appreciate it but what I really want to achieve is to not have to code authorization headers every time when I'm coding about requests. I want this to be done for me automatically by a single global middleware file. I thought this was possible after reading the server middleware documentation but in this case, I'm not so sure anymore. I think coding a composable instead of using the middleware will solve my problem...

Comment: Your idea is valid and I think that is achievable using middlewares but  I ran out of ideas on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the assignment in the following way instead:

`Object.assign(event.node.req.headers, { Authorization: 'Bearer test' })`

Comment: This does not work.